# AngularJs translation directive stop working when I change div class using jquery

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Well, being straight forward the problem is my $scope.$apply() is also not digesting the changes to rerun the translate directive.
I show you the HTML with applied translation directive and jQUERY code to change the class on resize of the windows (client).

HTML for menu:

```
<div id="navigation" ng-cloak>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="home.html" id="brand">BRAND NAME</a>

        <ul class='main-nav'>
            <li ng-class="{'active':activeLink == 'home'}">
                <a href="#/">
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{'active':activeLink == 'planning'}" data-trigger="hover">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class='dropdown-toggle'>
                    <span>Planning</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class='dropdown-toggle'>Goals</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#/goals/listview">{{'TOP_MENU.GOAL_LIST' | translate}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

HERE is the JQuery Code to make it responsive for screen size changes.

```
function checkLeftNav() {
var $w = $(window),
    $content = $("#content"),
    $left = $("#left");
if ($w.width() <= 840) {
    if (!$left.hasClass("mobile-show")) {
        $left.hide();
        $("#main").css("margin-left", 0);
    }
    if ($(".toggle-mobile").length == 0) {
        $("#navigation .user").after('<a href="#" class="toggle-mobile"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>');
    }

    if ($(".mobile-nav").length == 0) {
        createSubNav();
    }

} else {
    if (!$left.is(":visible") && !$left.hasClass("forced-hide") && !$("#content").hasClass("nav-hidden")) {
        $left.show();
        $("#main").css("margin-left", $left.width());
    }

    $(".toggle-mobile").remove();
    $(".mobile-nav").removeClass("open");

    if ($content.hasClass("forced-fixed")) {
        $content.removeClass("nav-fixed");
        $("#navigation").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }

    if ($w.width() < 1200) {
        if ($("#navigation .container").length > 0) {
            versionFluid();
            $('body').addClass("forced-fluid");
        }
    } else {
        if ($('body').hasClass("forced-fluid")) {
            versionFixed();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now What my solution was to get he nav element scope on which the jquery is applying class and call the $apply() on its scope. which is not working.

Solution Code:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
checkLeftNav();
// get the scope of element and apply $apply()
var sc = angular.element('.mobile-nav').scope();
sc.$apply();
```

});

But still when ever the screen size is changed to mobile view less than 840 I can see direct code values instead of translated text in menu like this. and When I change back to screen width more than 840 it shows correct translated text. I am experimenting this on chrome on my pc by resizing. I checked on mobile its not translating there too.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS provides two-way *data* binding, not two way *everything* binding. It's not intended to be used this way. `$apply()` only looks at the data model - it is the function you call when you want to say "Hey, Angular, I've updated the data model, come have a look!" That is literally its only purpose. There is no method in Angular designed to look at the DOM itself for changes - that's very inefficient and against Angular's philosophies anyway, which is why it ships without jQuery.

You might want to evaluate other frameworks that better support this kind of thing. However, if you really wish to do this you can easily convert it into a proper AngularJS module. The best way is to simply paste all of this code into a controller, and then change the window resize binding to use Angular's `$window` service, like:

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.bind('resize', function() {
    // Do my calculations here.
});
```

With your calculations would you compute the same variables but you would store them in scope variables and then adjust your template to use them. For example, what you're doing with `$(".toggle-mobile").remove();` could be replaced by:

```
if (windowElement.width > 840) {
    // Other code here
    $scope.isMobile = false;
} else {
    $scope.isMobile = false;
}
```

and in your template:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-mobile" ng-if="isMobile" ng-click="toggleMobile();"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Give it a whirl, play with it for a week or two, and you'll never go back to jQuery. It takes a lot of getting used to, but once you do you realize how broken the whole "I'm looking at my template and have no idea what mystery event handlers are bound to all this stuff" concept was to begin with.